# notify() in synchronized block

Tags: java

I have found the blow code in a project. But i cant understand why the only notify() method is in synchronized block .

```
synchronized(this){
  notify();
}
```

Is this code logical and if so what is the real purpose ?

Comment: _why the only notify() method is in synchronized block_ please explain yourself.

Comment: İ dont know so asked here

Comment: Well,I don't understand what you mean by _"the only notify() method"_, do you mean "only the notify() method"?

Comment: Yes it will be " only the notify() method "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notify( ) wakes up the first thread that called wait( ) on the same object.

```
class ThreadB extends Thread{
int total;
@Override
public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
        for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
            total += i;
        }
        notify();
    }
}
```

Like above example, we use notify to send information message(hey i finished my work, wake up !) to other thread which is waiting. So at your question, it is not meaningful

Comment: Thank you, my though was like yours

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to call `notify` only from a thread that owns the object's monitor. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--):

> **This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor.** A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - **By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.**
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.

*(My emphasis)*

Answer (score 2):

To understand why it makes sense, consider that there have to be other blocks synchronized on the same object, that will be waken up by this block.

Take a look at this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily incorrect but definitely a bad sign. Somewhere else in that code, there will be an unconditional `wait`. E.g.:

```
synchronized(this) {
    wait();
}
```

this might be working correctly now. But, if `notify` is ever executed before `wait` this will result in a deadlock.

Usually you want to wait on some condition:

```
synchronized(this) {
    while(!this.flag) {
        this.wait();
    }
}
```

and use `notify` like this:

```
synchronized(this) {
    this.flag = true;
    this.notify();
}
```

This will never deadlock on it's own and it's clear what we are waiting for.